# Handling Errors from Custom Role Provider C# MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling, roleprovider

I have build Custom Role Provider project working with MVC4 C# application and it works fine but when an error occur in role provider like SQL Server is down application receive error like:

Source Error:

```
Line 46:     <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="myRoleProvider">
Line 47:       <providers>
Line 48:         <add name="myRoleProvider" type="SDP.myRoleProvider.myRoleProvider,      >SDP.UtilyxRoleProvider" applicationName="SDPlatform" />

Line 49:       </providers>
Line 50:     </roleManager>
```

> Source File: d:\Projects\SDPlatform\SDPlatform\SDPlatform\web.config    Line: 48

I'm not able to catch and handle error on web app side. I catch it on Role provider side but I'm not able to handle it on Web App side..

Thanks

Comment: The error you've posted indicates a syntax error in line 48 of your web.config file

Comment: I think there is no chance to have syntax error only when SqlServer service is paused. But let me put this with more details. RoleProvder is seperate project implemented as custom role provider. My application work for weeks until something happens what cause error for RoleProvider and when error there happens it is manifested like I showed above. I guess that my Web App is not capable handling error in Custom Role Provider project or something like that and I would like to catch that error. Thanks\